# SipServlet support in Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, sip

I planned to create an application with SIP function. The initial idea was springboot+sipservlet. After several days' trial I failed to make it work. Here are some failure cases:

1.

```
@javax.servlet.sip.annotation.SipServlet(applicationName="myservlet", name = "MyServlet", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class MyServlet extends SipServlet {
    public MyServlet() {
        log.info("*** STARTED ***");
    }
...
}
```

The constructor was not invoked, even though @ServletComponentScan was attached to Application class.

2.

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class MyServlet extends SipServlet {
...
}
```

The servlet can bootup, but it seems an http servlet rather than a sip servlet.

sipservlet-1_1-api.jar was used.
Can anyone help on this? or is there any sample?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sip servlet api to be effective, it needs a sip servlet enabled application server. I am only aware of three such beasts: The abandoned sailfin from Oracle, an old variant of red hat's jboss, and open liberty from IBM. There might be another around, but I doubt that.

Try open liberty, that might be your best shot!